# How to extract GeoJSON vector layer coordinates from DOM, Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, geojson, jquery

I created a GeoJSON vector layer using OpenLayers 3 API, the vector layer is a county map. My goal is by clicking, I will be able to select the county and extract the coordinates. (like shown below) 
[image]

My current method of extracting the coordinates is once on.select, goes to the DOM and find the coordinates. Something like this:

```
var coords;
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
    map.addInteraction(select);

// var selectedFeature = select.getFeatures();
selectclick = select;
selectclick.on('select', function(e)
{
  if (e!== null)
  {
  console.log(e),
  coords = e.selected[0].c.target.s;
  console.log(coords);
  }
});
```

This way works find, but I had to manually go the DOM and find the coordinates myself, then write the location in variable "coords". This probably not a good solution when face dynamic environments. Is there a better way to find coordinates in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access source of your layer then access features of the source and coordinates of features with `getCoordinates()` method of `ol.geom.Polygon`. 
Try like this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '/your_counties.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
});

//call this whereever you want from
function getCoordinatesOfCounties() {
    var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
    features.forEach((feature) => {
        console.log(feature.getCoordinates());
    });
}
```

Comment: So, for my understanding, 'vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().getCoordinates()' would help me find the coordinates from the GeoJSON? I tried it, doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: `vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures()` returns `Array.<ol.Feature>`.  `getCoordinates()` is a method of `ol.Feature` not `Array.<ol.Feature>`. You have to call getCoordinates feaure by feature.

Comment: Thanks @himyata, I have a better understanding now! What if you want to find a specific coordinates of a single feature out of the the Array.<ol.Feature>, using jQuery method on.('select') ? Any idea?

Comment: I did some investigation, and finally solved my problem.. Thanks for get me on the right track, bounty is yours :)

Comment: Not working on V 3.0.0. Always returns blank array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @himyata, if you'd like to find coordinates during event, you will need to use `.selected[0].somemethod` to do so, an example is shown below:

```
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(selectClick);

selectClick.on('select', function(e)
{
  if(e!== null)
{
coords = e.selected[0].getGeometry
console.log(coords);
}
});
```